# picture fill out all col

Tags: html, css

I really have to figure this out now. I would like that a picture fill out whole my col-6. But how can I know how big the size of the picture should be? Should I set a height also?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col-6">
            <img src="img/fly_tying.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-6">
            <form action="flyUpload.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Upluad Fly</legend>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" value="name"><br>
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <input type="text" id="category" value="category"><br>
                    <label for="fishtype">Fishtype<label>
                    <input type="text" id="fishtype" value="fishtype"><br>
                    <button type="submit" value="submitFly">Submit My Fly</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-6{
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

height just set the auto. and make the img set width `100%`

Comment: @GAMITG this is not a comment, this is my answer. Just set the css img width into 100% .